# How do I add "Stand By" to the Start Menu in Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I've got Server 2008 running on a laptop.  I can get the system to "stand by" or "sleep" by using the appropriate hardware button or keyboard shortcut, but the option isn't available in the start menu alongside the other shut down options.  How can I add this?

Please note that I want to add this to the shut down options, not as a shortcut in the Start Menu or Desktop.

Comment: Can you set it as the default action? Right click on whatever it is now and choose Properties. Under the 'Power button action' drop down list is Standby an option? If not, I'd suggest the solution lies in some registry edit somewhere.

Comment: The "Power button action" list is greyed, with "Log off" selected.  I'm not sure if that's by a Group Policy configuration, or if that's enforced on Server 2008 naturally.  I'm fine with tweaking the Registry if it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Group Policy setting. Start->"gpedit.msc"->[enter]

Navigate where the image shows.

It may or may not work - I don't have Server 08 to test unfortunately. Google 'power button action (greyed|disabled)' for more info and post an answer if you find one.

[image: Set this to enabled]

Comment: Nice screenshot.  I love your inclusion of suggested Google search terms, as well as a possible solution.  I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score -1):

Refer this information:-

[Group Policy Settings for Start Menu and Taskbar](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617162(WS.10).aspx)

[Start menu power button does not show Hibernate](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsserver2008r2management/thread/9b68dedd-8fff-4a66-8073-c684430dfe74/) - "Answer by **Mervyn Zhang**"

[Desktop shortcut for the sleep command?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/desktop-shortcut-for-the-sleep-command/4e57f536-50a8-4942-a84a-290b3dea1ffb) -

Comment: Can you please post the pertinent details here, instead of just links?

Comment: @Iszi: Thanks for the comment. After a lot of search, I found this related links for your question. Can you please tell whats wrong in the links?

Comment: Nothing's wrong in the links (that I'm aware of - but I haven't had time to dig through them yet) but StackExchange answers should be able to remain relevant and useful without relying on pointers to outside resources which may or may not exist in the future.  You may cite those websites as sources, but links alone do not constitute an answer.

Comment: ok. Let me try, to find more better solution for you.